# when i try to upload a .flv video to a folder it says "count not fine the file "test.flv" (the file is in my desktop though)

Tags: c#, asp.net

//if video is .flv format save file to the specific folder

```
                if (upExtension == "flv")
                {

        File.Copy(fileupVideo.PostedFile.FileName,Server.MapPath("../"+playFile));

        operateMethod.catchImg(Server.MapPath("../" + playFile), Server.MapPath("../" + imgFile));

                    insertVideoInfo(playFile, imgFile);
                }
```

Comment: please also post your exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try `fileupVideo.SaveAs` instead of `File.Copy`.  `fileupVideo.PostedFile.FileName` will retrieve the name (and POSSIBLY the path) of the file on the client-side.  You can't access that from the server-side, and should use `.SaveAs` to save it to a file on the server first.

Comment: ok thanks it works, so if i wanted the client to be able to upload their video themself ,should i still use fileupVideo.SaveAs ? or i must change the command back to File.Copy & fileupVideo.PostedFile.FileName

Comment: If you want to know what the name of the file was as given by the client, then you would use `.PostedFile.FileName`.  That however is not the name of the file as it is on the server.  You can use `.PostedFile.FileName` as part of the filename you pass to `.SaveAs` if you want.  Just be sure to strip out all but the filename from it first (different clients submit different things, some even submit the complete path), and validate that it doesn't contain any harmful characters like `./\:` etc.